# Identify the SQL Server job that is triggering another job within the same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

There is a log shrink job within the server that despite being disabled is still being triggered by another job within the server. As there are many jobs within the server, what is the fastest way for me to identify which job is triggering this other shrink job?

Comment: It *really* depends how the job is being called, unfortunately. It might not even be another job. If you're *sure* it's another job then you could inspect the `dbo.sysjobsteps` table in `msdb`, looking for the job's name in the `command` column.

Comment: found the job in the table dbo.sysjobsteps but no job triggered it. Also realized that although the job is disabled, schedule is still enabled. Would that cause the job to still run? it did run at the time it is scheduled for.

Comment: No, a disabled job won't run at it's scheduled time. Otherwise I'd be getting errors from some of my historical jobs that have been disabled all the time. The "Next Run" column in SSMS Job Activity Monitor will continue to update the "Next Run" value, but the Last Run will be the last time it *actually* ran.

Comment: by some reason, by disabling the job multiple times it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below T-Sql Script to identify which job is triggering any specific Job—as long as the `Job_Name` or `Job_id` is mentioned specifically in `Job_Steps`:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SELECT 
    j.name, * from dbo.sysjobsteps as js
JOIN
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs as j ON js.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE 
    js.command like '%JOB_Name%'  -- Mention the Job Name here

-- WHERE js.command like '%JOb_iD%'   -- Mention the Job iD here
```